# music downloads not here

Tags: music, downloads, locate

I paid for two music downloads from ubuntu one music.

They charged me of course.   And guess what?
No sign if either soundfile anywhere on the computer.
Did a search of the home folder.

They're not in the music or ubuntu one folder, I looked.
Help, anybody?
thanks
Marc

Answer (score 3):

[From the Ubuntu One FAQ.](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/where-is-the-music-i-purchased-from-the-ubuntu-one-music-store/)

Check https://one.ubuntu.com/files for it.

To make them download automatically, make sure the "Purchased Music" folder is checked in the "folders" tab of the Ubuntu One application.

If they're not in one.ubuntu.com/files and/or they don't automatically download after you've told it to, then contact Ubuntu support.

Comment: @user125241 If this *doesn't* solve your problem, your best bet will be to use [Ubuntu One support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/).